# Show that a subset of the $2 \times 2$ matrices is an infinite cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups

> Let $M$ Denote the set of 2x2-matrices of the form
>   $$A=\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}$$ where the entries are integers. Show that
>   $M$, with respect to matrix multiplicaation, is an infinite cyclic
>   group.

To prove this, i should just prove that the set $M$ and $C_{\infty}$ are isomorphic right? Since if they are isomorphic then they are same, which means that $M$ is a infinite cyclic group.

So, i contruct a bijection $f$ as
$$f: M->C_{\infty}$$
such that $f(m_1*m_2)=f(m_1)*f(m_2)$. If i can show this, then $M$ and $C_{\infty}$ are isomorphic and therefore $M≈C_{\infty}$. This bijection $f$ takes $A$ to 1 $A^2$ to 2 etc or?

I have now construct an bijection. Next thing I have to do is to find the element $x$ such that every member of $C_{\infty}$**(or shall i take $M$?)** is a power of $x$. This element $x$ is said to generate $C_{\infty}$; $C_{\infty}$ = < x>.

After I have done that, i define $f$ by the rule
$$f(n)=x^n$$
there $n$ belongs to $Z$. This generator $x$ is the matrix  $A$ above:
$$f(n)=x^n=\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}^n$$ I get stuck here and i don't know if i have done right so far :/

**The short solution in the book**

The function taking matrix $A$ to m is an isomorphic from $M$ to $Z$(**why the integer?)**. The significnt is that
$$\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}*\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&m+n\\0&1}$$

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: $m$ determines completely the matrix $A$. What is $A^2, A^3, \ldots$?

Comment: The matrices are on the form $A^n=\pmatrix{1&nm\\0&1}$ @Sigur

Comment: What happens with $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^m$?

Comment: Well, $B^m=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}^m=\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}$. Or did you mean anything else with "what happens with"?@Sigur

Comment: i know that the set $Z$ is the only infinite cyclic group. But I can't figure out how to show that  $M$ and $Z$ are isomorphic. And how shoul i define my function $f$ and have i used right generator ?

Comment: For each integer $m$ you can use $A^m$ and vice versa.

Comment: Could you check my attempt and tell me where i am doing wrong and give some hints please ? i prefer to do explained solutions and let people check them and correct me if i am thinking wrong or something like that.

Comment: You say "so I construct a bijection" - but do you really? You have not mentioned (at least not in your post) how you actually construt it.

Comment: i have problem with constructing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define a group homomorphism $\phi:M \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & m \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1  \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto m$$

Of course, you'll want to prove that this is actually a homomorphism.  From there, it's not too difficult to confirm that $\phi$ is both surjective and injective $\Longrightarrow$ $\phi$ is bijective and thus an isomorphism $\Longrightarrow$ $M \cong \mathbb{Z} \Longrightarrow M$ is an infinite cyclic group since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite cyclic group.  (Note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group under addition generated by $1$).

Comment: thanks for the help. I think i need to rest a little and then continue to study. Haven't taking any break for a long time now. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem; it's usually pretty good to get your mind away from the math every couple hours and take a walk or something.  I'm glad I could help, and if you're good to go, don't forget to accept the answer (click the check mark) so it doesn't show up as unanswered for future Math:SE denizens :)